# Return sequence and return state in Keras LSTM layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

So I've been studying a little bit about LSTMs and how to implement them using Keras API. But I'm a bit confused on what the arguments return_sequence and return_state do exactly. While reading through some books and articles I see that the cell state and the hidden state are passed as an input for the next cell to compute it's states. And I've also seen some examples on how these arguments to the constructor end up resulting in a different output shape.
If I understood it correctly when both are set to True then, when the model is used to predict on a new batch of data not only does it return the output but the entire sequence produced by the model as well as the cell states for the respective terms in the output sequence. At first I thought this arguments allowed you to use the entire sequence of hidden states and cell states as input for the next cell, but that would mess up the architecture and overall schema of the network and wouldn't really be a LSTM anymore, not to mention possible dimensionality problems that would rise up.
Sorry for the long post but I tried to make my line of reasoning as clear as possible hoping someone might shed some light on this topic and help me by saying if my understanding is actually correct or not.

Comment: May be [this](https://github.com/AtrCheema/Miscellaneous_DL_Tutorials/blob/master/return_sequences_vs_return_states.ipynb) can be of helpful to you!

Comment: I tried the example provided but it doesn't really help in understanding what the lstm outputs are even in the case where return_sequence and return_states is set to False.